# ArcGIS Pro - Datamodel export to Visio | Diagrammer successor

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-data-model, arcgis-diagrammer, visio

Can someone tell me if there is a possibility for ArcGIS Pro to create a Visio export from a geodatabase?

For ArcGIS Desktop there was a diagrammer here, but I don't know of a successor.

Does anyone have an alternative so I can get the objects from the geodatabase to Visio for an ERM?

Comment: There are some options available to get diagrams of your geodatabase, but they are all outside of the ArcGIS software suite.  [Enterprise Architect](https://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/16.1/index.html), [SQL Power Architect](https://bestofbi.com/products/sql-power-architect-data-modeling/), among others.